# What does $\forall x \phi \rightarrow \psi$ mean?

Tags: logic

If I have a formula $\forall x \phi \rightarrow \psi$, how can I know if it means $(\forall x \phi) \rightarrow \psi$ or $\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$?

Comment: Optimality, only one of them makes sense, considering the number of free variables in each of $\psi$ and $\phi$. But it _ought_ to be clarified.

Comment: Without explicit convention (see you textbook), usually the quantifiers applies as little as possible. Thus it is $(\forall x \phi) \to \psi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to how WFFs are formed, the former interpretation is correct, and the correct expression is

$$(\forall x \phi \rightarrow \psi)$$

and not

$$\forall x(\phi \rightarrow \psi)$$

Notice the parenthesis around the entire implication. You don't need parenthesis over $\forall x \phi$, as it is a WFF already.

I do think that

$$ (\forall x \phi) \rightarrow \psi$$

is more readable, though, even though it's not an official WFF.

Answer (score 1):

It's a notational convention: quantifiers bind more tightly than Booleans, so the former interpretation is correct. In my opinion, though, it's a bit obnoxious to write it like that and parentheses really should be included.

*Although sadly I've seen this deviated from occasionally - but I've never seen deviation from this convention **in a textbook on logic**, so it should serve you well.*

(For me, the obnoxiousness comes from the relative rarity. I wouldn't consider "$x^2-3x-4$" to be obnoxious, even though one could interpret it incorrectly if unfamiliar with PEMDAS. On the other hand, I *would* consider $x\div y\div z$ to be obnoxious. So there is an element of subjectivity to my assessment here.)

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on whether $\phi,$ and $\psi$ are formulas including $x$,  and even then, without parentheses indicating either interpretation you provide, then we must assume the former of your options.

Without parentheses displaying the scope of the universal quantifier for $x$, you should take $\forall x \phi \rightarrow \psi$ to mean $(\forall x\,(\phi))\to \psi$ (where the quantifier only refers to the occurrence of $x \in \phi$).

Although, by convention, if all one is given is $\forall x\,\phi \to \psi$, we can only take the quantifier to apply to $\phi$, it is rather careless to write it this way.  As you show in your question about what this might mean, readers shouldn't be left to guess one or the other; rather, the author should should write either $$(\forall x(\phi)) \to \psi,\; \text{ or else }\;\forall x \big(\phi \to \psi)$$ depending on the scope of the quantifier on $x$, in order to help make themselves clear.  Without parentheses, $\forall x$ applies only to $\phi$; however, if one intends for $\forall x$ to bound all of $\phi \to \psi$, then one must include **all** of the scope of the quantifier in parentheses.

Comment: How can $\forall x(\phi\to \psi)$ mean either?

Comment: I think I've made myself clear, now, @Arthur.  Thanks for commenting.